# C++ - Best way to exit from main

Tags: c++, multithreading

In my main function there are some objects that do works in background until the destructor is called like in the following snippet:

```
#include <iostream>

class MyBackground {
public:
    MyBackground()
    {
        m_workerThread = std::thread(&MyBackground::work, this);
    }
    ~MyBackground()
    {
        g_exit = true;
        workerThread.join();
    }

private:
    void work()
    {
        while(!m_exit);
    }

private:
    std::atomic<bool> m_exit{false};
    std::thread m_workerThread;
};


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    MyBackground object;

    // here ther's some async background work
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;

    // ~MyBackground -> here threads are stopped
}
```

I need a way to block main until some extern signal occurs. My first attempt was something like this:

```
#include <csignal>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

using namespace std

atomic<bool> g_Exit{false};

void signalExit(int)
{
    g_Exit = true;  
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    signal(SIGINT, signalExit);
    signal(SIGTERM, signalExit);

    MyBackground object;

    while (!g_Exit)
        this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::seconds{1});

    // here ther's some async background work
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;

    // ~MyBackground -> here threads are stopped
}
```

But I'm not sure this works well. I thought is better use `condition_variables` like the following snippet:

```
#include <csignal>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>

using namespace std

bool g_exitFlag = false;
condition_variable g_exitCondition;
mutex g_exitMutex;

using Lock = unique_lock<mutex>;

void signalExit(int)
{
    Lock lock{g_exitMutex};
    g_exitFlag = true;
    g_exitCondition.notify_one();
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    signal(SIGINT, signalExit);
    signal(SIGTERM, signalExit);

    MyBackground object;

    Lock lock{g_exitMutex};
    g_exitCondition.wait(lock, [](){return g_exitFlag;});

    // here ther's some async background work
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;

    // ~MyBackground -> here threads are stopped
}
```

Which of the best implementations is correct. Are them correct? I'm not "experts" in multithreading programming.

Comment: What about [sigwait](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sigwait.3.html) ?

Comment: That's good, what a pity that's not on Windows also

Comment: I think the condition variable solution is better because it avoids polling.  Polling is a non-optimal solution since it requires the CPU to wake up periodically, and adds an unnecessary delay to the shutdown process.

Comment: Use a semaphore. On Windows, if [`ReleaseSemaphore()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms685071(v=vs.85).aspx) is async-signal-safe, you can block in `main` on a call to `WaitForSingleObject()` then have your signal handler call `ReleaseSemaphore()`.  On POSIX systems, `sem_post()` by standard must be async-signal-safe, so on a POSIX system, call `sem_wait()` to block in `main()` and have the signal handler call `sem_post()`.  I'd post this as an answer if I knew for sure `ReleaseSemaphore()` is async-signal-safe.

Comment: Is it that different from `conditional_variable`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not a slightly different design where your background worker thread isn't created and destroyed by the `MyBackground` class, but the thread is created in the `main` function? Then the `main` function can simply call `join` on the thread before it exits, and it will block until the background thread is done.

Something like

```
class MyBackground {
public:
    void work()
    {
        while(!m_exit)
        {
            // Do background work
        }
    }

private:
    std::atomic<bool> m_exit{false};
};

int main()
{
    MyBackground background;
    std::thread background_thread(&MyBackground::work, background);

    // Do foreground work

    background.join();  // Wait for background to exit

    // Implicit return
}
```

---

Another solution, if the thread is supposed to continue when the `main` function returns, is to [*detach*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/detach) the thread. Then it will work independent of the main thread, and the process will not actually exit until the thread has exited.

Note that this requires the `main` function to not just return or `exit`, as that will end the process including killing all threads. Instead you need to just exit the "main" thread. Unfortunately this is not possible using the standard C++ thread interface, but you have to use platform native functions. For example on POSIX systems (like macOS and Linux) you use [`pthread_exit`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_exit.html).

Comment: Yes, this is how multithreaded programs that I've seen dealed with that.

Comment: I don't like this solution because I want to exit smoothly my application when an external signal trigger (like `SIGINT` or `SIGTERM`)

Comment: @elvis.dukaj Then the first solution with the single `atomic<bool>` global variable looks like the best (and most certainly the simplest) solution to me.

Comment: This does the same as the OP's code. In the OP's code the `join` is called from the automatically called `MyBackground` destructor.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use a std::weak_ptr in main() to check if the strong ref count is nil to terminate. Pass the only strong reference pointer to other threads to enable main() to exit smoothly. Use std::conditon_variable instead to avoid closing threads waiting on condition_variable to reduce CPU usage during polling for checking if the weak_ptr expires or not.

```
void worker_thread(std::shared_ptr<int>& pulse)
{
    // do something
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(2));

    pulse.reset(); // reset to terminate main() too from any other threads
  }

void main()
{
    std::shared_ptr<int> pulse = std::make_shared<int>(1);
    std::weak_ptr<int> weak_pulse(pulse);

    std::thread([&](){ worker_thread(pulse); }).detach();

    while (auto strong = weak_pulse.lock())
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(100));

}
```